# interpolate string in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

In my application I need to show a string in bold and red color.
My below code is returning

```
<span style="font-weight:bold;background-color:red">MALE</span>
```

But I want to return the text "MALE" in bold and red color.

```
angularJS:
$scope.fullName = function (item) {
        var searchType;
        if (item.SearchType == 'MALE') {
            searchType = '<span style="font-weight:bold;background-color:red">MALE</span>';;
        }
        else {
            searchType = '<span style="font-weight:bold;background-color:red">FEMALE</span>';;
        }
        return item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName + ' ' + searchType;
    }

HTML:
 <zf-accordion auto-open="false">
        <zf-accordion-item ng-repeat="item in Individuals" title={{fullName(item)}}">
            <p><span>{{item.FirstName}}</span>
            <span>{{item.LastName}}</span><br />
                <span>FullName</span></p>            
        </zf-accordion-item>
    </zf-accordion>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for. Because you are using the `fullName` function to populate an attribute, you might not be able to use HTML in that attribute (generally HTML attributes cannot contain HTML within them). Note you also have mismatched quotes on the title attribute in your code...

Comment: I'm confused. It looks like what you claim it is returning is what you want.

Comment: Oh! Are you saying that your web browser is showing the literal text `<span...>`? That Angular is escaping your raw HTML?

Comment: That's not what `interpolate` means.

Comment: @henry is using http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/accordion.  The top code labeled angularJS is the scoped function he's using below where he wrote 'HTML'.  This is laid out confusing but it does make sense.

Comment: I want "male" and "female" should be shown in red and bold

Answer (score 0):

I think I initially misunderstood the code you had written
In this case you're probably going to want to add a ng-class to the zf-accordion-item tag which will hopefully add it onto the title element rendered.

```
$scope.fullName = function (item) {
    if (item.SearchType == 'MALE') {
        searchType = 'MALE';
    }
    else {
        searchType = 'FEMALE';
    }
    return item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName + ' ' + searchType;  
}

(accompanying css)
.male {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I want only "male" and "female" should be shown in red and bold. Not the full name